# Passing parameter while injecting and retrieving using InjectionPoint

Tags: java, javabeans, cdi, inject, qualifiers

This is relevant to one asked in [Pass Parameter to Instance of @Inject Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994716/pass-parameter-to-instance-of-inject-bean)

but i need some different approach for my implemenation.

For passing parameter while injecting, a custom qualifier can be created like :

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface SendInject{
    @Nonbinding
    int value() default 0; // int value will be store here
}
```

The class to be injected need to be annotated with `@SendInject` as:

```
@SendInject
public class Receiver{

   int in;

   private int extractValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
        for (Annotation annotation : ip.getQualifiers()) {
            if (annotation.annotationType().equals(SendInject.class))
                return ((SendInject) annotation).value();
       }
       throw new IllegalStateException("No @Initialized on InjectionPoint");
   }

   @Inject
   public Receiver(InjectionPoint ip) {
        this.in= extractValue(ip);
   }
   ..........
  }
```

And while injecting `Receiver` all the members needs to use the custom qualifier `@SendInject` . like:

```
  public class Sender{

      @Inject
      @SendInject(9)
      Receiver receiver;
   ..................

    }
```

I do not want to use `@SendInject` everytime i inject Receiver because its not necessary to pass parameter at few points for my implementation. Is there any way that i can customize the custom qualifier while injecting `Recevier` so that it can be used only when some parameter need to be passed?

I tried doing it so, but getting `Ambiguous dependency error` while deploying my component.

Comment: The more appropriate thing here would be to use a producer method and read the value in the producer method, looking up the appropriate values for all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means you want to have two types of Receiver (one is `@SendInject` and one is `non-@SendInject`) . You should let CDI to know how to create them.

For example , you can use a producer method to create `@SendInject`Receiver and use bean 's constructor to create `non-@SendInject` Receiver :

```
public class Receiver {

    int in;

    public Receiver() {
    }

    public Receiver(int in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    private static int extractValue(InjectionPoint ip) {
        for (Annotation annotation : ip.getQualifiers()) {
            if (annotation.annotationType().equals(SendInject.class))
                return ((SendInject) annotation).value();
        }
    }

    @Produces
    @SendInject
    public static Receiver createSendInjectReceiver(InjectionPoint ip) {
        int in = extractValue(ip);
        return new Receiver(in);
    }
}
```

And inject different `Receiver` type as usual :

```
public class Client{
      /************************************
       This receiver is created by constructor
      **************************************/
      @Inject
      Receiver receiver1;

      /************************************
      This receiver is created by producer method  
       **************************************/
      @Inject
      @SendInject(999)
      Receiver receiver2;
}
```