# How to pass parameters to instantiation of a CDI @Dependent bean?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

How to pass runtime parameters to the instantiation of a `@Dependent` bean, obtained by `Instance<T>.get()` or equivalent in CDI?

For instance, consider the code:

```
@Inject
Instance<Person> instance;
...
var name = "Some One";
var bean = instance.get();
bean.setName(bean);
```

It may be desirable to pass the parameter in instantiation, to make the object immutable for example. Something like

```
@Inject
Instance<Person> instance;
...
var name = "Some One";
var bean = instance.get(name); // ?
```

Is there a syntax for that in current CDI?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37691838/cdi-injection-with-parameters-wheres-the-instance

Comment: another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994716/pass-parameter-to-instance-of-inject-bean/23012543#23012543